# Optimization of a function of a positive definite matrix and its inverse

Tags: matrices, matrix-analysis, matrix-theory, global-optimization

This question is a little ill-posed, but I've been playing with some equations and am just wondering if this resembles any known problems that have been solved.

Suppose I have two real, positive definite (square) matrices $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{C}$, and I wish to find another real, positive definite matrix $\mathbf{B}$ such that
$\mathbf{A B} + \mathbf{B}^{-1}\mathbf{C}$ is as close as possible to identity.

I'll entertain any reasonable definition of "close" that makes the problem tractable.  Maybe minimization of $\| \mathbf{A B} + \mathbf{B}^{-1}\mathbf{C} - \mathbb{I} \|$ for some choice of norm.

Does anyone have any insight or experience with such a problem?

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: It reminds me of Sylvester's equation. There however we have no inverse.

Comment: I wonder if the minimization problem could be cast in terms of a Frobenius norm.

Answer (score 2):

You are actually looking to solve the continuous [algebraic Riccati equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_Riccati_equation). For convenience, I will write your $B$ as $X=X^T$. Then the equation you're trying to solve is simply

$$ X - XAX + (-C) = 0$$

Or even more explicitly, writing the Cholesky factorization of $A=BB^T$

$$ \left( \frac{1}{2}I \right)^TX + X\left( \frac{1}{2}I \right) - XBB^TX + (-C) = 0$$

The solution of an algebraic Riccati equation using Hamiltonian matrices is a standard topic in control theory. But I would instead refer you to [the "care" command in MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/care.html).

Comment: But in many cases this algebraic Riccati equation has no real solutions.

Comment: Excellent point. In order to get a real symmetric posdef $X$ "close" to solving the ARE, we would have to reformulate the problem into a semidefinite program.